# TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.dataproc.v1.WorkflowTemplate got str

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to write a Google cloud function that imports a Dataproc Workflow template from storage, and invokes the workflow. I am getting the above `TypeError` when trying to instantiate the template. Here is the offending piece of code:

```py
        # create workflow client
        workflow_client = dataproc.WorkflowTemplateServiceClient()
        parent = 'projects/{0}/regions/{1}'.format(project_id, region)

        # submit request
        operation = workflow_client.instantiate_inline_workflow_template(
            request={'parent': parent, 'template': '{0}'.format(workflow_json)}
        )
```

The value for `workflow_json` is definitely valid json and is of the `dict` type which is required by this function.

Here is the contents of my requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-dataproc==2.0.0
google-cloud-logging==1.15.1
google-cloud-storage==1.32.0
PyYAML==6.0
urllib3==1.26.16
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the resolution mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50545#issuecomment-872229474)? It looks like a known issue.
The resolution is reorder the line from `lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py`(may vary on what python version you are running) file.

from:

```
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
```

to this:

```
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
```

Comment: How would that work in a GCP cloud function? Since I am not running this code locally or on a server?